# Elasticbeanstalk Django issues with ondeck vs current version

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Elasticbeanstalk to deploy a Django application.  Within the `.ebextensions` directory I've got the following (this is just a subset):

```
commands:
    00_pip_upgrade:
        command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
        leader_only: true

    01_pip_install:
        command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt
        leader_only: true

container_commands:
    111_collectstatic:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python /opt/python/ondeck/app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
        leader_only: true
```

The issue is that anything with `ondeck` isn't found.  I am having trouble finding AWS documentation regarding the transitions between `bundle`, `ondeck`, and `current` directories.  When I ssh into the instances I don't see any directory at all for `/opt/python/ondeck`.

Can someone help to explain if `/opt/python/ondeck` should still be used or what my issues may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after speaking with AWS support I have a little more information.  My inability to find any documentation regarding `/opt/python/ondeck` is because each EB could use different paths based on the its settings. If you need help understanding the directories in your current situation, checkout cloudformation. Additional important information:

1. The `commands` section of `.ebextensions` will not have access to the staging (new deployment code) because it exists before it
2. The `container_commands` will have access to staging code so I needed to move some items here.  For me `/opt/python/ondeck` worked as expected within this section.